# ModelForm with multiple values not responsive

Tags: python, django, django-forms, modelform

so I encountered this problem with Django and ModelForms. Everything loads as expected but when I'm trying to send data by hitting Enter nothing happens.

**models.py**

```
class Drinks(models.Model):
    name    = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    number  = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=2000) 
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**forms.py** ( I tried with list and tuple as well )

```
class DrinksForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Drinks
        fields = [
            'name',
            'number'
                ]
```

**views.py**

```
def DrinksView(request):
    form = DrinksForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        print("VALIDATION COMPLETE")
        form.save()
    
    form = DrinksForm()
    return render (request, 'form2.html', { 'form' : form })
```

**template.html**

```
    <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    </form>
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Drinks
admin.site.register(Drinks)
```

I did all necessary migrations.
Any Ideas what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your form doesn't have a submit button:

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

For your view, consider this instead:

```
def new_drink_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DrinksForm(request.POST)
        # check if valid
        # ... 
    else:
        form = DrinksForm()

    return render (request, 'form2.html', { 'form' : form })
```

Be sure to import the DrinksForm form.